# MySQL query that returns distinct count of records against one colum while using a second column as the filter

Tags: mysql

So here is what I am trying to accomplish. I have a single table, transactions, that has multiple entries of a sessionId with transactionCodes. I am trying to count distinct SessionId's only if they do not contain a specific transCode.

So basically transactions could look like:

```
sessionId    transcode
1            100
1            101
1            102
2            100
2            101
2            102
2            103
```

What I need to do is along these lines.

```
select count(distinct sessionId) where transCode != 103;
```

I would expect the above to only return a single record but in practice it obviously does not because my novice level SQL query returns me far more records than it should!

Comment: It should return exactly one row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to handle it. Perhaps the easiest is via a `NOT IN ()` subquery:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT sessionId) 
FROM transcode
WHERE
  sessionId NOT IN (SELECT sessionId FROM transcode WHERE transcode = 103)
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14bda/3

It can also be done via a `LEFT JOIN` looking for `NULL` on the right side table. This may be more efficient than the `NOT IN ()` on larger tables.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT t.sessionId)
FROM
  transcode t
  /* LEFT JOIN against a subquery returning only sessionId with a 103 transcode */
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT sessionId FROM transcode WHERE transcode = 103
  ) texclude ON t.sessionId = texclude.sessionId
WHERE
  /* and retrieve only those where these is *no match* on the joined subquery */
  texclude.sessionId IS NULL
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14bda/2

Comment: Bingo! The second one completed in about 9 seconds on my table vs about 50 seconds for the NOT IN () approach. Kudos for the lightning fast reply!

Answer (score 1):

this will filter out the session ids that have the given transcode, and then count the rest:

```
select count(distinct sessionId) 
from transactions t1
where not exists (
    select 1 from transactions t2 
    where transCode = 103 and t1.sessionId = t2.sessionId
)
```

Comment: `NOT IN` will be much more efficient than `NOT EXISTS`. The second runs the sub-query against every row in the table, while the first only compares the `sessionid` against a list that's built one time.

Comment: The linked post says "if NULL is allowed", and it's pretty apparent from the query posted that a NULL `sessionid` would not be acceptable. I didn't say *always* more efficient; I meant in this particular case. If I'd thought it was *always*, I would have downvoted your answer in addition to commenting, and I didn't downvote. :-)

Comment: lol, ok. but i think their conclusion in that post is that both of the queries are treated identically, if the fields are not null